# how to create a array of labelfields

Tags: blackberry

I have `n` number of data which has to be added to a label field which in turn has to be added to hfm. I am setting the single data in to label field as :

```
final LabelField desc = new LabelField("", LabelField.FOCUSABLE);
final LabelField desc1 = new LabelField("", LabelField.FOCUSABLE);

    Vector data = (Vector) listEvent.get(keys);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
       EventData ee = (EventData) data.elementAt(i);

    String Summary=    ee.getSummary();
     if (time.getText().equals(sTime)) {
                                                                                                             desc.setText(Summary);
     }
    else{
                 desc1.setText(Summary);

    }
}
    HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager_left18 = new HorizontalFieldManager() {

                 horizontalFieldManager_left18.add(desc1);
                 vfm.add(horizontalFieldManager_left18);
                    vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

    HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager_left17 = new HorizontalFieldManager() {

                 horizontalFieldManager_left17.add(desc);
                 vfm.add(horizontalFieldManager_left17);
                    vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
```

In the above code i loop over vector and set the data into `labelfield` and adding the label to `hfm` later.

Now the case is the vector data has more than one summary data,and the data is getting overridden in `labelfield`,i need to keep `n` number of summary data into lablefield and add to new `hfm`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to Blackberry; Welcome to BB Developement;

> Try to do like this:

```
public class Abc extends MainScreen
{
private LabelField labelField[];
public Abc() 
{
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI() 
{
    int size=10;
    labelField=new LabelField[size];//Here put your size; i.e., "data.size()"

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        labelField[i]=new LabelField("LabelField: "+(i+1), Field.FOCUSABLE);
        add(labelField[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you have any doubts come to this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java

Comment: then how to handle array  in horizontal manager ?as i am adding label this to hfm then hfm to vm

Comment: @sheetal_roswal, the answer seems okay to me, if that is not working for you, it will be nice if you make a sketch of the UI and post it with your question.

Comment: @Rupak sheetal here,i have few queries on the same are you available on chat?